# how do you display a html in view on ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have a module that should render a menu depending on the user roles.
We used to use `cancancan` gem but since we got a new specification it's being deprecated.

I have an association that goes like this. A many_to_many relationship with `User` and `Role`, another many_to_many relationship with `Role` and `Menu`, so a `User` has a nested many_to_many relationship with `Menu`.

What I'm trying to do is render a menu depending on the user role. so I have this helper module:

```
module MenuHelper
      # ! MENU MAPPING ===============================
      MENU_NAMES = {
        orders: '<%= main_menu_tree Spree.t(:orders), icon: "shopping-cart", sub_menu: "orders", url: "#sidebar-orders" %>',
        workflows: '<%= tab *Spree::BackendConfiguration::WORKFLOW_TABS, label: Spree.t(:workflows),  icon: "flash" %>',
      }
      # ! MENU MAPPING ===============================

      # this will return menu names
      # @params {ARRAY} menu_names are the allowed menu that the user can access by its role
      # @returns {ARRAY}
      def user_menus(menu_names = [])
        samp_arr = []
        menu_names.each do |m_n|
          samp_arr << MENU_NAMES[:"#{m_n.downcase}"]
        end
        samp_arr
      end
    end
```

and on my `shared/_menu.html.erb` I have this.

```
<%  spree_current_user.menus.pluck(:name).each do |n|%>
  <ul>
    <%= n%>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

on the view though it will turn into a string. I expected this behavior but is there a way to evaluate this as a method? since `main_menu_tree` and `tab` is just a method or maybe you could suggest a better way to solve this? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have `menu_names` you can create a new template (we name it as partial) for each menu, see the example:

```
app/
  views/
    menus/
      _menu_name_1.html.erb
      _menu_name_2.html.erb
```

If you create these partials, you should be able to do something like:

```html
<%  spree_current_user.menus.pluck(:name).each do |menu_name| %>
  <ul>
    <%= render "menus/#{menu_name}" %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

It will concatenate the name of menu with the path of the file to render and all should work fine!

Comment: ohhhhh. this will work. I think? but let me try. thank you for this.

Comment: Let me know if it helps :)

Comment: `render "menus/#{menu_name}"` is enough

Comment: @aRtoo Did it works? Don't forget to accept the answer to help other people ;)

Comment: @DimitriusLachi yes this works but I had created a work around so I wont have to create partials. but ill accept this. thanks much sir. :)